# How to fix "Warning : Unprotected Private Key File" on Windows 10

Tags: database, dbeaver

I am attempting to do a simple connection to a SSH server using OpenSSH for Windows using a private key, and it shows this.
I can't permit pem file and I keep getting this error message "Warning unprotected private key file"

[image]

Comment: You need to use the correct permissions on your key file.  Only the owner of the key can have access to the file.  You can change the permissions as the owner of the file.

Comment: Please [edit] and paste the text in, as the text in a screenshot is not text-searchable.

Comment: SOLVED! I removed all the other users to accessibility.